# Protocol Buffer - c

Tags: c, struct, protocol-buffers, grpc

```
`stuct` apple
{

    int a;
    char c;

};
struct b
{
int count;
`stuct` apple a[10];
};
```

How can implement these structures to a message field in `protobuff` C.
I am looking for a alternative method to write struct apple a[10] other than writing 10 times on `protobuff`.
Can you help me?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i get it.

```
message b
{
  message apple
  {
    int32 a;
    string c;
  }
  int32 count;
  repeated apple a;
}
```

This is the prototype message.
Use vector implementation of dynamic arrays to use it.It will help to crate N no.of objects of a structure.